# map a struct to a function in go

Tags: go

```
import (
    "net/url"
)

type Route struct{
    filepath string
    url url.URL
}

func hello(){
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}

func main() {

    routes := map[Route]func{
        Route{url.Parse("/home"), "/var/www/index.html"} : hello
    }

}
```

I cannot figure out what syntax error is preventing me from mapping a Route struct to a function.

I am getting this error:

> ./main.go:24:26: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting (
>
> ./main.go:25:8: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting comma or )

Comment: The first error is telling you what you need, `func` isn't a type, but `func()` is.

Comment: I figured some of it out. url.Parse("/home") returns err, and Url. Its trying to return 3 params total for a 2 param Route struct.

Comment: Structs don't have "parameters", the path and URL are in the wrong order for your struct declaration, and url.Parse returns a `*url.URL` and an `error`, not a `url.URL`. You might want to checkout the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which covers a lot of basics to help get you going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. type is not `func` but `func()`
2. you need to take care of `url.Parse`'s error

There is a refactored code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

type Route struct {
    filepath string
    url      *url.URL
}

func hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}

func mustParse(rawURL string) *url.URL {
    parsedURL, err := url.Parse(rawURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return parsedURL
}

func main() {

    routes := map[Route]func(){

        Route{"/var/www/index.html", mustParse("/home")}: hello,
    }

    fmt.Printf("routes: %+v\n", routes)

}
```

The solution with panic might not be the best if you don't know the input dispositions.